# command PASTE returns additional sumbol (standard_in) 1: syntax error in bash

Tags: bash, paste, bc

I have bash function `get_total` which create output like this:

```
0.5 0.5 0.2 1.7
```

there is one space for separates

if I run the command

```
get_total|paste -sd+
```

I will have output

```
0.5+0.5+0.2+1.7
```

It is OK to pass to bc

However this command

```
result=$(get_total|paste -sd+|bc)
```

gives me output like this

```
0.5+0.5+0.2++1.7
```

you may see two ++ which calls syntax error in bash

Mau someone helps me, please? Where does appear ++? How can I avoid this?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your result `echo "0.5 0.5 0.2 1.7" | paste -sd+` results in `0.5 0.5 0.2 1.7`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest making use of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this. Any of the following will do:

```
$ get_total | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "}{s+=$1}END{print s}'
$ get_total | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)s+=$i; print s}'
```

If you want to use [bc](/questions/tagged/bc), then you can do this:

```
$ get_total | tr  ' ' '+' | bc
```

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the double '+', so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. 
`get_total` output data into column

I have modified uses `tr` it now looks like this `get_total | tr [:space:] '+'` 

But I still have `0.0+1.0++` however at the end of string now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is the best way but the code works for me.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # The -z test means true if empty. ! negates (i.e. true if not empty).
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
        result=$(get_total | paste -sd+ | tr -s '++' '+' | bc)
        echo $result
    fi
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$app00" "$app01")
```